# Error when posting: using Cartthrob Permissions cannot locate cartthrob_field_model

Tags: cartthrob, fieldtype, permissions

When I add the cart throb permissions fieldftype to a channel and try and post I get the error: Unable to locate the model you have specified: cartthrob_field_model

Cart throb is up to date ver 2.4 and CT permissions ver 2.3.3

Can anyone shed some light on where that error is coming from?